# Can I "simulate" a virtual network PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares

I have to test a program on my PC that retrieve a path from a DB and then work on files on this path. The problem is that this path refers to \\STORAGE-AREA\etc and in my network there isn't any machine with this name.
So my question is: can I create or simulate a PC or a network share with the specified name that for example will refers to C:\TemporaryFiles ?

My OS is Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply make your local machine fake that host.

Open the file `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` with your favorite text editor. Note that you'll have to run the program using elevated privileges (as administrator).

At the end of the file add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 STORAGE-AREA
```

Once this is done, create your local fake folder for this and share it as `etc`, which then should allow you to access `\\STORAGE-AREA\etc` providing its contents.

Note that you may also use any other IP address in case you'd like to use a NAS or any other PC for that.

Comment: Now I can "reach" \\STORAGE-AREA, but it wants me to authenticate and even if I insert the correct credentials it doesn't authenticate

Comment: I had this problem http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926642
I solved applying the solution n.2